# Reading excels sheets, and creating a DataFrame. SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Tags: python, excel, pandas, syntax-error

Im trying to read an excel with 12 sheets.

```
DemandaAS= pd.read_excel('Demanda AS.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
month=pd.Series([11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Now Im trying to create a data frame with each sheet.

```
ind=0
sheets=['NOV.20','OUT.20''SET.20','AGO.20','JUL.20','JUN.20,','MAY.20','ABR.20','MAR.20','FEB.20','ENE.20','DIC.19','NOV.19']
for i in sheets:
    '_'.join(['Demanda',month.loc[ind]])=DemandaAS[i]
    ind=ind+1
```

but i have th next error:

> File "", line 3

> '_'.join(['Demanda',mes.loc[ind]]) = DemandaAS[i]

> ^

> SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Answer (score 0):

Per [`read_excel` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), if you specify `sheet_name=None` you return all sheets in Excel workbook.

So actually `DemandaAS` is a dictionary of data frames where keys are the original sheet names. So avoid duplicating separate data frames to flood your global environment.

Simply use underlying data frames accordingly. To be clear, you lose no functionality of the data frame if stored within containers like `list` or `dict`:

```py
DemandaAS['NOV.20'].head()
DemandaAS['OUT.20'].tail()
DemandaAS['AGO.20'].describe()
```

Such containers even help serialize same operations:

```py
for i, df, in DemandaAS.items():
   print(df.describe())
```

Even concatenate all data frame elements together if all sheets were similar in structure:

```py
# DICTIONARY COMPREHENSION TO ASSIGN NEW COLUMN TO SHEET NAME
DemandaAS = { k: v.assign(sheet=k) for k, v in DemandaAS.items() }

master_df = pd.concat(DemandaAS, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Has worked! Also with ```pd.DataFrame.pivot``` could obtain a Data Frame with each month in a column. Thanks a lot!